# Why mysql say "syntax error" if there's not any?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query but when I execute it mysql say me:

> Error de SQL (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'END WHILE' at line 1

Here's the query:

```
BEGIN 
    DECLARE _ProductoId;
    DECLARE _ProductoCosto INT;
    DECLARE _Cantidad INT; 
    DECLARE _id INT DEFAULT 129;


    WHILE _id < 143 DO

        SET _ProductoId = SELECT Compra_ProductoId from tblcompradetalle WHERE CompraDetalleId = _id;
        SET _ProductoCosto = SELECT ProductoCosto from tblproducto WHERE ProductoId = _ProductoId;
        SET _Cantidad = SELECT CompraDetalleCantidad FROM tblcompradetalle WHERE CompraDetalleId = _id;

        UPDATE tblcompradetalle 
        SET compraDetalleSubtotal = (_ProductoCosto * _Cantidad), 
        SET ProductoPrecio= _ProductoCosto WHERE CompraDetalleId=_id;

        SET _id = _id + 1;

    END WHILE; 
END
```

The problem is that I review the query line by line but I couldn't find any syntax error. Which is the syntax error?

Comment: Remove one of the two SET keywords from UPDATE. Only one is needed.
Ex: `udpate t set col1 =1, col2 = 2;`

Comment: also i believe *datatype* is required when declaring a local variable, e.g. `DECLARE _ProductoId INT;`   (i'm not entirely sure that's required. if its not required, and is omitted, then what *datatype* does MariaDB assign to the local variable? for the benefit of future readers, we should go ahead and specify it, even if its not required.)

Comment: I remove the additional "set" and put datatype all variables. But the error remanins. console shows previews errors. After each variable say that that variable is Unknown for ex: Error de SQL (1193): Unknown system variable '_ProductoId'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two SET keywords.  Syntax is `UPDATE tbl SET a=1, b=2 WHERE...`.

Format your update with the SET command at the end of the line, and you will easily remember not to include two SET keywords.

```
UPDATE tblcompradetalle SET
        compraDetalleSubtotal= (_ProductoCosto * _Cantidad),
        ProductoPrecio= _ProductoCosto
WHERE CompraDetalleId=_id;
```

Comment: I remove the additional "set" and put datatype all variables. But the error remanins. console shows previews errors. After each variable say that that variable is Unknown for ex: Error de SQL (1193): Unknown system variable '_ProductoId'

Answer (score 0):

I think you misspelled update query with double SET. Mariadb docs gives an example of this query.

```sql
UPDATE [LOW_PRIORITY] [IGNORE] table_reference 
  [PARTITION (partition_list)]
  SET col1={expr1|DEFAULT} [,col2={expr2|DEFAULT}] ...
  [WHERE where_condition]
  [ORDER BY ...]
  [LIMIT row_count]
```

Comment: I remove the additional "set" and put datatype all variables. But the same error remanins. Also reviewing the console it shows a previews errors. After usage each variable appear this: /* Error de SQL (1193): Unknown system variable '_id' */
END WHILE;
/* Error de SQL (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'END WHILE' at line 1 */

Comment: This is an outstanding move but try to copy **_id** from declare and paste where it should be

Comment: I mean after each variable console say that that variable is Unknown for ex: Error de SQL (1193): Unknown system variable '_ProductoId'. Is rare to me cuz the vars are declared.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this stored procedure

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `my_procedure`()
BEGIN 

    DECLARE _ProductoId int;
    DECLARE _ProductoCosto INT;
    DECLARE _Cantidad INT; 
    DECLARE _id INT DEFAULT 129;

   set _id = 129;
    WHILE _id < 143 DO

        SET _ProductoId = (SELECT Compra_ProductoId from tblcompradetalle WHERE CompraDetalleId = _id);
        SET _ProductoCosto = (SELECT ProductoCosto from tblproducto WHERE ProductoId = _ProductoId);
        SET _Cantidad = (SELECT CompraDetalleCantidad FROM tblcompradetalle WHERE CompraDetalleId = _id);

        UPDATE tblcompradetalle 
        SET compraDetalleSubtotal = (_ProductoCosto * _Cantidad), 
         ProductoPrecio= _ProductoCosto WHERE CompraDetalleId=_id;

        SET _id = _id + 1;

    END WHILE; 
END
```

If you give me some example data with create table  i can test it further

Comment: CALL `my_procedure`()
Error de SQL (1054): Unknown column 'ProductoPrecio' in 'field list'

Comment: Then check if such a column Poductoprecio exists in the table tblcompradetalle

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there's another ways but the following worked, as stored procedure:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `spCompraDetalle`()
 LANGUAGE SQL
 NOT DETERMINISTIC
  CONTAINS SQL
  SQL SECURITY DEFINER
 COMMENT ''
 BEGIN


   DECLARE _ProductoId int;
  DECLARE _ProductoCosto INT;
 DECLARE _Cantidad INT; 
 DECLARE _id INT DEFAULT 129;


WHILE _id < 143 DO

    SET _ProductoId = (SELECT Compra_ProductoId from tblcompradetalle WHERE CompraDetalleId = _id);
    SET _ProductoCosto = (SELECT ProductoCosto from tblproducto WHERE ProductoId = _ProductoId);
    SET _Cantidad = (SELECT CompraDetalleCantidad FROM tblcompradetalle WHERE CompraDetalleId = _id);

    UPDATE tblcompradetalle 
    SET compraDetalleSubtotal = (_ProductoCosto * _Cantidad), 
     CompraDetallePrecio= _ProductoCosto WHERE CompraDetalleId=_id;

    SET _id = _id + 1;

   END WHILE; 

 END
```

...

```
 CALL `spCompraDetalle`()
```